# Variable UITableview form

Tags: iphone

Im trying to create a variable questionnaire UITableView form for iPad.

I would like some advice what is the smartest way to do this. It has variabels that only needs to be asked if the previous question is YES.

So im using a UISwitch but how can i dynamically add rows below this question for the related questions.

Comment: Apple provide loads of documentation for doing things like this as well as tutorials and there are loads of clear detailed tutorials on the web that can be found with a quick Google! Please do at least some research before asking a question.

Comment: What is  **variable questionnaire**? Also, share some code about the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually as simple as your question.
   Just check if the user has answered YES, if so, add the question you want to display to the user to your array with which you fill your tableview cells.

```
[yourArray addObject:@"whatever you want to display"];

[yourTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: If i do a reloadData don't the questions already been answered get lost? But thanks for the info!

Comment: @user1713954 : No, the questions answered doesnt disappear. iPhone sdk provides the functionality similar to "refresh" whenever we reload tableview. According to apple developer docs : the table view redisplays only those rows that are visible.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically adding rows you can use : `[tableView reloadData];`

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a logical problem. A basic approach to get you started can be along the following lines.. Assume the number of sections in your table view equal to number of base questions (Whose answer determines if some other questions should be presented). Each section has 1 row if the answer is NO or has rows = 1+dependent questions. Reload the table(for ease of implementation) each time something is answered.
If you have multi level base questions, this approach can get tricky but you definitely can apply the same logic to solve that as well.